# Why widgets' events triggered before view completely rendered?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

Let say we have a view like this:
[image: mockup]

```html
<script id="my-view" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
            <input data-text-field="name"
                   data-value-field="id"
                   data-role="dropdownlist"
                   data-bind="source:wellDataSource,events:{change:onWellChange,dataBound:onWellDataBound}" />
            <div data-role="tabstrip" data-bind="visible:isAnyWellExist">
            <ul class="bd-doc-navigation-tabstrip" data-freezable="false">
                <li class="k-state-active">Home</li>
                <li>Products</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```js
var _view = new kendo.View("my-view", { model: _viewModel});
_view.render("#container");
```

When I render the view I expect all the three widgets rendered and then events of them triggered but when the *dropdownlist* rendering finished it's *databinding* and *databound* events fires before the *tabstrip* and *grid* rendered. So I can't access the *tabstrip* and *grid* widgets in those events.

Why this happens? And is there any solution or workaround to be sure events happens after the view rendered totaly?

Comment: **I mark following answer as accepted answer but any more detailed answer about my question appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo DropDownList has a `DataSource`, FYI the event `DataBinding` and `DataBound` automatically triggered when data has been collected from server.

Therefore to prevent it to do so you have to prevent the data initialization of DropDownList. You can change DropDownList `AutoBind` property to `false`, so it won't make a request to server when its in initialization phase. After page rendered completely you can trigger its `DataSource` to call `read` method.

Your code should be like this

```
<input data-text-field="name"
       data-value-field="id"
       data-role="dropdownlist"
       data-bind="source:wellDataSource,events: change:onWellChange,dataBound:onWellDataBound}"
       data-auto-bind="false" />

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#dropdown").data().kendoDropDownList.dataSource.read();
});
```

[Kendo DropDownList AutoBind Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-autoBind)

Comment: Thanks bro, your answer lead me to final solution(workaround), by the way it forces me extra coding and always care about setting auto-bind to false, and calling datasource. Another thing to mention is that `fetch()` is wiser than `read()` because read send request to server every time called.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on how your UI works, and what kind of widget are you using. Good luck :D

Comment: **I mark this answer as accepted answer but any more detailed answer about my question appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Each widget loads individually and parallel to each other, so it's very much possible that one widget has fully databound while the other one doesn't exist yet. The events don't wait until the page has fully loaded.

Depending on how you've implemented it, a work-around could be to move your code accessing the tabstrip and grid to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
});
```

To force the Kendo datasource to behave synchronously, you can try configuring your datasource transport with `async: false`:

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            async: false,
            url: function (data) {
                return "/Home/Product";
            },
            dataType: "json"
        },
    },
});
```

I found a way to check if all widgets have been bound. See [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/combobox/how-to/detect-when-all-widgets-are-bound).

Example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var promises = [];

        var change = function() {
            this.deferred.resolve();   
        }

        var categories = $("#categories").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "CategoryName",
            dataValueField: "CategoryID",
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
            },
            requestStart: function() {
                this.deferred = $.Deferred();
                promises.push(this.deferred.promise());
            }
          }
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");

        var products = $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "ProductName",
            dataValueField: "ProductID",
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
                },
                requestStart: function() {
                    this.deferred = $.Deferred();
                    promises.push(this.deferred.promise());
                }
            }
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");

        categories.dataSource.bind("change", change);
        products.dataSource.bind("change", change);

        $.when.apply(null, promises)
            .done(function() {
                console.log("done");
                console.log(categories.value());
                console.log(products.value());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but we are writing a complex SPA with nested views and we need to do this many times after document ready, so document ready won't help us. It is strange for me if JS is single thread so why an event triggered while another method (render) is not completely runned? Any other idea or help?

Comment: Kendo UI executes Ajax calls to populate it's widgets. Those are asynchronous by default. Perhaps disabling this might help you, not sure.

Comment: By setting `async: false` rendering rest of view pauses until the ajax  gets the response from server. So it don't solve the problem. Another thing that I figure out but not sure is the first time _databound_ occurs after all widgets are rendered but next time the problem occurs because this time data are ready in _datasource_ and upon widget is bound to _datasource_ it's _databound_ event triggered.